# @PropertySource on a bean not picked up by Spring in JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring

I've got 2 different maven projects: project A and project B, where A is a maven dependency of B. Project A has a class annotated with `@PropertySource`:

```
@Component
@PropertySource({"classpath:spring-files/resource.properties"})
public class BeanAImpl implements BeanA{

@Value("#{\'${list.of.some.properties}\'.split(\',\')}")
    private String someProperties;
}
```

In project B, I want to be able to define BeanAImpl. So I define it in my JavaConfig class of project B:

```
@Configuration
public class ProjectBConfig{

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
@Bean
public BeanA beanA() {
    return new BeanAImpl();
}
```

I get a BeanCreationException, since the injection of the List into "someProperties" has failed. If I add to my `@Configuration` class (in project B) a component scan annotation for BeanAImpl's package, then the context will load successfully. Also, if I add the `@PropertySource` declaration to the config class - then it's going to work. But it seems that simply defining beanA in the configuration, does not take into account its annotations. I also tried changing beanA from `@Component` to `@Configuration`, which did not help.

Is there a way for me to have BeanAImpl inject the value from the properties by simply defining it as a bean, without needing to add extra configuration? Why is this happening?

Comment: Use `@Value` Annotation.

Comment: I am using it in BeanAImpl. Is there anywhere else you think I should add it?

Answer (score 0):

`@PropertySource` annotation should be on class annotated with `@Configuration`, something similar to this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:spring-files/resource.properties"})
public class ProjectBConfig{
```

Or you can create separate configuration class in project A.

See [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) for details of @PropertySource annotation.